# Как создать админ панель на Django?

Tags: python, django

Всем привет,у меня есть бот на aiogram,хочу написать для него админку на django,пишу в pycharm,подскажите с чего начать,где хранить файлы,как создавать траекторию для админки?Вот траектория моего бота,пока не на сервер,запускаю,через бат файл

Answer (score 0):

Пишете звичайний проект на джанго за док.
Налаштовуєте веб хуки
Запускаєте ngrok
Через АРІ телеграм, ставите сервер ngrok
Обробляєте запити на стороні сервера джанго

Якщо щось не зрозуміло і гугл не допомагає, то уточніть ваше питання